# I need to zoom an UIImageview which is in UIView in ScrollView

Tags: objective-c

I need to zoom an UIImageview which is in UIView in ScrollView. I have tried this:

```
[scroll setMinimumZoomScale:2];
[scroll setZoomScale:10];
```

but it does not work 
Why?

I implemented the method

```
 - (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

return img1;
```

}

It works but moves the images of the other pages and stop scrolling

Comment: You need to do a lot more stuff that includes delegate method implementation to enable zoom. Read apple docs for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

have you set a maximumZoomScale?  That has a default value of 1.0.

definition:

```
@property(nonatomic) float maximumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0. must be > minimum zoom scale to enable zooming
```

Try:

```
[scroll setMinimumZoomScale:2];
[scroll setMaximumZoomScale:12];
[scroll setZoomScale:10];
```

Comment: does not work. I have tried to call - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 but never called

Comment: have you set the delegate of he scrollview?  `[self.scroll setDelegate:self];`